# SQL Server Always ON - LOGPOOL_CONSUMER wait and replication issue

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I'm facing a strange issue in one of my customers AG. There're 4 instances under this AG.

Staring a few days ago, my customer complains about some query (`SELECT`) timeouts issues. When I faced this issue yesterday, I was not able to run a simple `sp_WhoIsActive`. When I did successfully run `sp_WhoIsActive`, there's a lot of `LOGPOOL_CONSUMER` wait info.

I've googled it, but only a few info about this "internal wait". Anyone have face it before? Any tips to check it out?

Comment: Since you're also unable to run WhoIsActive, the issue you're most likely hitting is THREADPOOL. You'll want to consider enabling the Remote DAC and running it from there the next time you're having an issue.

Comment: THREADPOOL wait is the "hand of god" saying no more.   I hope I've never see that wait state in my career.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous or asynchronous AG's?   How are your AGs "layed out"?

https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/logpool_consumer/
This wait type is when a thread is waiting for an operation to do with the log pool. This is an in-memory cache of recently flushed log blocks, to help avoid log readers having to do physical reads of the log file (e.g. for sending log blocks to asynchronous availability group replicas).

How fast or slow is your log activity replicating over to your AG replicas?
https://www.sqlshack.com/measuring-availability-group-synchronization-lag/
Good AG queries to "get to know"...

Comment: Hi, It was asynchronous (all of secondary replicas). All instances are hosted inside Azure VMs inside a specific region.

Comment: So "All" primary and secondary replicas are inside Azure.   Are your secondary AG replicas open for "read"?   And did you run sp_WhoIsActive against your primary when it hung?  Same question for your customers... are they reading/selecting against the Primary or secondary replicas.   Asynchronous replicas "shouldnt" cause primary to hang as transactions don't need to commit to secondary before confirming/blessing transaction.   They can if they were synchronous - right?

Comment: Hi,

Yes, primary and secondaries are located inside Azure. All secondary replicas are open to read.

I didn't ran sp_WhoIsActive in primary, but I'll try next time.

My customer is performing some reads on primary, but the vast majority runs in secondary. As I stated, I never run sp_WhoIsActive when the incident happens, but I didn't observe any problem on primary.